# Optimizing sql queries with NOT IN clause on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I would like to be able to select all entries from the orders table where a certain product has been ordered prior to 2019 but not after it. The table has close to 7M entries and the below query seems to take almost ~4 minutes to run. Note that in the orders table productId is a foreign key to products table and is indexed. Could we rewrite the below query to be more optimized and better in performance time ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM orders o
WHERE o.year < '2019'
AND o.productid NOT IN (
                        SELECT distinct(productid)
                        FROM orders
                        WHERE year > '2019');
```

Please find below the output from explain commmand

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key                    | key_len | ref                      | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | o     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL                     | 2124177 |    33.33 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o2    | NULL       | ref  | FK_orders_product | FK_orders_product | 4       | test-db.o.productid |       3 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: Please run `explain` before your query and post the result in the question. Add table description as well

Comment: Why do you mention a foreign key to `products`? You don't use that table in this query.

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Please find the output from explain select in the question above. Thanks

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders`

Answer (score 1):

You could use *not exists*.

Hopefully the `year` column is not a varchar so you should not be using string literals. Presumably using `select *` means there won't be any duplicates so you should remove *distinct*.

Your year ranges also exclude 2019 completely, so presumably one of your predicates should be equal to 2019?

```
select *
from orders o
where o.year < 2019
  and not exists (
    select *
    from orders o2
    where o2.productid = o.productid
      and Year >= 2019
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did add the changes you mentioned above and it has definitely improved/corrected the results returned. The query time still seems to be around the same time, but not sure how to completely optimize it yet. Thank you

Comment: @shashankhr - Please provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames - Please find the output from explain select in the question above. Thanks

Comment: @shashankhr - And for Stu's NOT EXISTS version?

Answer (score 0):

Probably both uses of `DISTINCT` were useless.

Add this composite index (to at least help the NOT EXISTS):

```
INDEX(product_id, year)
```